# Error with Indicator in AngularJS when using angular-carousel

Tags: angular-carousel

I am new to AngularJS. I implemented a simple slide show application using angular-carousel. But when I click on the bullet items it's throwing error like 
'TypeError: e.assign is not a function'.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

rn-carousel-index, this is the reason I got this error.

When you want use Indicator in the carousel, use some variable like  rn-carousel-index='carouselIndex' in the and  in indicators. You need to define a value for this in the controller.

$scope.carouselIndex = 0 or 1